# Separated console output from devenv (project by project) for Jenkins

Tags: c++, build, jenkins, continuous-integration, devenv

I have Jenkins up and running with one job, building one big VS solution using `devenv`.

Console log output looks like the normal VS output (changed example):

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.101010.2.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: MyProject2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
3>------ Build started: Project: MyProject3, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
3>Compiling...
3>Compiling...
1>Main.cpp...
2>Project.cpp...
```

Is there any possibility to have separated log (project by project) in Jenkins. Or maybe some plugin to track each project build log. Because when build fails it's hard to follow log tree to find all project occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

There is **[Collapsing Console Sections plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin)**. It allows to define start/end points of "sections", once the log has those, they are marked on the console log and can be collapsed for easier reading

Comment: Slav, thanks. It could help just to decrease number of log lines, but I really would like to 'collapse' log project by project (including all compiling threads).